# Generate an error screen in a PHP Script form searching a MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I'm new with PHP, but I want to do some research on MySQL. I've got this code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "db_user01", "******")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database_test");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from testdata where UserID like '$term'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<br/> Id: '.$row['UserID'];
echo '<br/> name: '.$row['Cliente'];
echo '<br/> mail: '.$row['DDT'];
echo '<br/> phone: '.$row['Status'];
echo '<br/><br/>';
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>retrieving db info form</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="http://webserver/searchdb.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="term" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code performs a search on the database "database_test" in table "testdata", for the field "UserID" and prints the data related to that user ID. Based on the user who searches, the info has the correct ID ("userID") and it works just fine. Still, I've got a little trouble. When a user writes a bad UserID, I need to generate a screen telling him "Wrong ID", but when this happens the script generates a blank screen (no errors or anything). I really don't know how to print or show a text saying that the user input a wrong user ID.

I repeat, everything works fine but I need to generate an error screen or print a message to the user when they input a wrong user ID; otherwise they get a blank screen.
I'm really new to PHP, so please, I need your help with this ASAP! I'll be alert on this thread! Thank you very much!

---

UPDATE: I'm posting my code with the latest changes; it still doesn't work. Now it doesn't even work with correct user ID :( Please check it out and tell me where the error is. The only modification I made is adding a "back" link to the search page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

mysql_connect ("localhost", "database_test", "****")  or  die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("db_contents");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from trackingmc where UserID like '$term'");
if (mysql_num_rows() == 0) {
echo 'wrong ID, check your id. <a href="http://www.myserver.com/search.html">Go back</a>';
}
else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<br/> Id: '.$row['UserID'];
echo '<br/> name: '.$row['Cliente'];
echo '<br/> mail: '.$row['DDT'];
echo '<br/> Status: '.$row['Status'];
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo '<a href="http://www.myserver.com/search.html">Go back</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Often, on production web servers, for security reasons, error displaying is turned off. Try writing:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

at the beginning of your script, and see if it displays error.

Instead of using die function, probably you should check if mysql_error() returns something, and then use print to display an error message.

Comment: Hi, can u help me with the changes, so how exactly i must disable the "die" function? or how i can check if mysql_error() returns a msg? plz remember i`m a newbie :(

Comment: hi again, i already put the "error_reporting" lines but still the same hwen i put a correct userid.. it works fine, gives me result etc.. but when i try to put a inexistent or bad userid.. the page goes blank.. i need a msg to appear saying: "wrong ID, check your id" :( thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: sorry. I misunderstood the problem. I posted another try.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you perform the query, you don't check the number of returned rows. Try something like that:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "db_user01", "******")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database_test");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from testdata where UserID like '$term'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
    echo 'wrong ID, check your id.';
}
else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<br/> Id: '.$row['UserID'];
        echo '<br/> name: '.$row['Cliente'];
        echo '<br/> mail: '.$row['DDT'];
        echo '<br/> phone: '.$row['Status'];
        echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, i`m going to check it now!! but it looks only for the ocurrence of not input anything on the search field.. let me check and i tell you! :)

Comment: Bad news! :( i`ll test your code, and added something: a link back to the search form, and this is the error: **Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_num_rows() in /home/muevecol/public_html/buscar.php on line 11wrong ID, check your id. Regresar **

Comment: Charles, i will post under my original post my actual code, can you check it out? i dont know hwere could be the error! :S

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the argument for mysql_num_rows(). Pass it the $sql variable, like I corrected into the example.

Comment: thank you charles, i`m to che it right now, i`ll post the result when i finish!! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to help debug is adding two lines under your mysql_query statement:

```
echo mysql_errono() . "<br />";
echo mysql_error() . "<br />";
```

I've found a lot of problems that prevent basic echoing of anything can be found by adding in debugging lines like the ones above, as well as:

```
echo "Something happens here!";
$var = func1( );
echo "Something has happened!";
```

Where if something bad happens in `func1()` then you'll see the first debug, but not the second, and will then know to add more debugging lines into `func1()` (or, if you can't do that, then you can check your parameters you're passing into that function).

Comment: so, i have to add those 5 lines of code under the "mysql_query" line? plz be a little bit more specific.. i`m totally a newbie! thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not all five, no. Just the first two. Sorry 'bout that. The last three were more an example of using debugging to find the problem spot, and then figuring out what's wrong in that spot.

Comment: ooops!! test it but anytime got worst!! this is the error i got: ***Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_errono() in /home/muevecol/public_html/buscar.php on line 11** so the error could be **echo mysql_errono() . "<br />";** <--that ERRONO ITS THE CULPRIT I THINK!

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's `errno()`, not `errono()`, that's a mis-type on my part, lol. Sorry.